# MySQL Dump Not Working

Tags: php, sql, mysql

every time that I issue the following command "mysqldump -uroot -ppassword database > database.sql" I get the following error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near". Please help me.

Here is more info if it helps.
I'm using a macbook running on Mavericks and I'm using MAMP PRO.

Comment: Are you putting spaces between -u user and -p password?

Comment: Please post the output from `mysqldump -V` (capital V) as well as the version of MySQL Server you are running (`SELECT @@VERSION;`)

Comment: Is there anything in `my.cnf` for `[mysqldump]` that might be running some broken query after connect?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the output that I received after issuing the command `msqldump` was `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near` and the version of the MySQL server that I'am running is **5.5.25**.

Comment: ohhhhhhhh... `mysqldump` is a *shell* command... not a mysql statement.  You need to be at a `$` or `#` system prompt, not the `mysql>` prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your **database.sql** has an error on some parts of the queries? Did you try to export it in any database softwares like phpMyAdmin, MySQL browser, Workbench? Does your database has many transactions or data? Please try also **mysql -u root -p database > database.sql**. Hope it helps.

Comment: There is no space after `-p` in the mysql client utilities.  It looks and seems very wrong, but that's how they work.  -pPASSWORD or --password=PASSWORD are the only two ways to supply passwords on the command line.  Not even --password[space]PASSWORD works, like you would expect.  If the password needs quoting then -p'PASSWORD' (which seems *extremely* wrong, but works) or --password='PASSWORD' can be used.  Any space after -p or --password causes the client to assume you want to be prompted for the password.

Comment: `database.sql` here is the resulting output file and has nothing to do with the input. Whatever's in `database.sql` will be stomped and replaced with the output of this command.

Comment: When I try to export my databases through phpAdmin, everything works perfectly. It just doesn't work when I do it through the MySQL commands in the terminal.

Comment: @BryanHeredia did you try this? mysql -u root -p database > database.sql

Comment: @Shudmeyer Yes I have, and it gives me the **You have an error in your SQL syntax** message.

Comment: oh i get it did you enter the mysql prompt? Please do this on the shell not on the mysql commands.

Comment: said also by @Michael-sqlbot mysqldump is a shell command... not a mysql statement. You need to be at a $ or # system prompt, not the mysql> prompt.

Comment: @Shudmeyer GOD BLESS! It Worked! I had to enter the full path in the shell! Thank you very much I can now proceed with my studies!